# How can I switch a preview image in an `org-mode` buffer to its source block?

Tags: org-mode

In `org-mode`, I use preview images for various things such as latex formula and linked images (e.g. `[[file:xxx.png]]]`). At times, I need to change the code for these and switch back to the code view. I know I can use things
like `C-c C-x C-l` for LaTeX and `M-x org-toggle-link-display`.

*Is there a simpler way to switch back to the source, e.g. by double clicking the image or using one key-binding/command on it, for all types of preview images?*

Comment: There was one (at least for LaTeX fragments): the very busy `C-c C-c` would restore the code view (I don't remember if it toggled, but I think not). However, that was deleted some time ago in order to make the key less busy. I don't think there is anything like what you are looking for now, but it should not be too hard to add a function that figures out what org-element is at the location of the event and does the necessary to flip the state if it finds the element to be either a LaTeX fragment or a link (and does nothing otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of my comment, here is a function that toggles the state of a link or a LaTeX fragment at point. It's bound to `C-c t` (for "toggle") only because that was undefined in my Org mode keymap:

```el
(defun ndk/toggle-state-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((ctx (org-element-context)))
    (pcase (org-element-type ctx)
      ('link           (org-toggle-link-display))
      ('latex-fragment (org-latex-preview)))))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c t") #'ndk/toggle-state-at-point)
```

It does nothing if the context at point is *not* a link or a LaTeX fragment.

N.B. `org-latex-preview` was introduced in Org mode 9.3 and is replacing `org-toggle-latex-fragment` which is deprecated. For Org mode versions < 9.3, replace the `org-latex-preview` above with `org-toggle-latex-fragment`.
Thanks to @tinlyx for pointing out the problem.

Comment: Thanks. It seems `org-toggle-latex` should be `org-toggle-latex-fragment` in my Emacs 26.